# How correctly append data to HTML from jQuery and Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I am working on implementing a "load more articles" functionality using Python, Flask and Ajax. Everything is working from the server-side but I don't know how to append the new data to the HTML by using jQuery.

I have the following json object which is sent from the server side:
[image]

And the following jQuery and Ajax code in my HTML template:

```
<script type=text/javascript>
  $(function() {
    $('a#get-more').bind('click', function() {
      $.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + '/_get_the_data_from_serverside', {
      }, function(data) {
        $("#more").append(data.stories[0].storycontent);
      });
      return false;
    });
  });
</script>
<span id=more></span>
<a href="#" id=get-more></a>
```

But it doesn't work as you can see, the data from the json object like "storycontent" is not being appended to the HTML.

Any ideas?

Comment: You need id="more", you are missing the "   "

Comment: You have to copy the div or something which is you are repeating in Python. Just replace at the HTML of that with your json object values.

Comment: @JesperHøjer Done that and it didn't change anything.

Comment: You don't get any error in the console, if you press F12?

Comment: @SunilPachlangia How exactly? Unfortunately I don't know jQuery functionality well.

Comment: @JesperHøjer No errors.

Comment: What happens if you just hardcode some text, instead of the data.stories[0].storycontent? Like $('#more').append("Test test test")

Comment: @JesperHøjer It's working, so as I said my problem is in manipluting the JSON object in the picture to append it to the HTML, I don't know should it be 'data.stories[0].storycontent' or 'data.[0].storycontent' or ''data.0.storycontent'.. etc? I don't know the correct form for this.

Comment: The way I see it, I would think that it should be data[0].storycontent without the dot between data and [0].

Comment: Can you show the raw json result (text) instead of the parsed version?  Looks like it should be `data[0].storycontent` but that's unusual.  There's no "story" or "stories" in the parsed picture.

Comment: Thank you all! "data[0].storycontent" was the correct one, I hope you can add it as an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path for the json should be data[0].storycontent.
Like so:

```
<script type=text/javascript>
  $(function() {
    $('a#get-more').bind('click', function() {
      $.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + '/_get_the_data_from_serverside', {
      }, function(data) {
        $("#more").append(data[0].storycontent);
      });
      return false;
    });
  });
</script>
<span id="more"></span>
<a href="#" id=get-more></a>
```